# Animation Nodes: How to keep the Radial perfect loop when adding iterated rotations to each instance

Tags: animation-nodes, mathematics

I have this simple AN radial setup:

[image: AN initial setup]

And this simple loop to give incrementing rotations to each instance:

[image: Loop setup]

And this setup allows me to keep the perfect loop intact regardless of how many instances I put, that's one problem solved:

[image: Instances]

What I need to do now is make an algorithm so that I can add a stronger rotation to each instance, but I can't figure it out. So far I only managed to work by multiplying by 2 the whole function, but I need it to be smooth, i.e. with a Float value so that I can animate it.

TL;DR: I need this to still be a perfect loop when I make the rotations to each instance stronger:
[image: Problem]

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you a lot, I am not very good at math but I am trying :/.

Comment: Sorry I can't help, but there's a reason for that. I can't get the addon installed to save my life! Really bummed, too. :(

Comment: I don't use AN, so I won't answer, but in order to align the square with a square, you need its rotation (along its axis) throughout one full revolution (rotation around the world center) to be divisible by 90. The first node in **Get Rotation Values** section calculates how many degrees of the revolution is done between each instance: `360 / number_of_instances`. Similarly you can divide 90 by the number of instances to get a minimum (positive) angle of rotation. Then you can multiply it by an arbitrary (manual input) **whole number** (integer) to get multiples of this value.

Comment: thanks for this tip, although this works to get a smoother result, that's what I am trying to avoid, I wanted to use a float value so I can multiply it extra smooth, without the use of a whole number.

Comment: But the sum of the rotations has to be divisible by 90° in order for the first and last squares to align. This integer I mentioned is there to make sure that's the case. Imagine, that throughout whole revolution, the square rotates along its axis by 90°. For 100 steps this would mean 90°/100 = 0.9° rotation for each step. Decrease this step, and the squares just won't align, because they will sum up to less than 90° which is the smallest radial symmetry of a square. The mentioned integer is there only to multiply this 0.9° while maintaining divisibility of the sum of steps by 90°.

Comment: I guess that's how it must be. Again idk math so I was thinking there's a different way. Anyway thanks mate! Got some clarity now

Comment: @MattChowski it all comes down to the very simple logic: two squares are aligned only if one has the same rotation as the other, or +90 degree rotation, or +180, or +270. Notice on the GIF as the rotation divided by 90 is further and further away from nearest integer, the squares align less and less, up until the `.5` is reached, then the squares start getting *"closer"* again. https://i.imgur.com/ONQyWWh.gif